# Visual C++ can't find 3rd party ATL Class

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, com, atl

I recently wrote an ATL object using Visual Studio 2012. I 'know' it is registered because I can use it in C# (after adding it to the resources). However, I want to write a C++ application using the same library. But, when I try to invoke it as a CComPtr, intellisense prompts me that it can't find the class.

C# code:

```
using BpFFTLib; // <- my ATL object with the Interface IFFT and class FFT

namespace comtest
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            BpFFTLib.IFFT fft= new BpFFTLib.FFT();

            // do fft stuff, it works, I tested it
        }
    }
}
```

and then the C++ code:

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlctl.h>

int main(void){

    CComPtr<IFFT> pIFFT;
    pIFFT.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FFT);
    // do the same fft stuff, but in C++
    return 0;
}
```

I'm still pretty new to COM and the other darker arts of Windows, but my understanding leads me to believe that the C++ snippet is equivalent to the C# snippet. Am I missing some include directive?

I'm sorry I can't really provide a completely compilable example. That would mean including the whole FFT library that I wrote as well. But, I know it works because I tested it in C# and all the parameters are marshalled properly in the function calls and everything.

Later...

So I realized that I need to include the header and references to the .dll (my ATL object). However, it is still not working. I get a million mysterious linker errors. There must be an easy way to do this that I am not aware of.

Comment: It is not equivalent, you did not do the same thing you did in your C# project.  Note how you added a reference to your ATL type library, that got the compiler to know what `BpFFTLib.IFFT` meant.  Writing COM client code in C++ is a *lot* harder than it is in C#, but you must get started with the `#import` directive to do the equivalent thing.  Lots of MSDN help about #import and the C++ COM helper classes, be sure to read it.  And consider whether it is worth the hassle, that C# program surely works just fine.

Comment: Thank you @Hans Passant. This is becoming obvious to me. I want a very elegant solution, but maybe I need to suck it up an do some copy/paste of code. It pains me somehow that I can't just make a library and use it anywhere, but I realize that this is missing the point of COM and ATL in some respect.

Comment: Hmya, COM client code in C++ will never be particularly elegant.  You are trading universality and speed for convenience.  Not the worst, the C++ helper classes help a lot, having to do it in C is truly brutal.

Comment: It won't work unless you call CoInitialize() first.  And, of course you have to #import the type library.